# Jquery dialog does not disabled all the inputs and buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I Use jQuery Dialog to display a details form when creating a new user.
I want to disable a form while performing an ajax request to the server to create the actual user in the DB.

I use `$("#UserDetailsDialog").dialog("disable");` method to disable the dialog.

it seems that this method only affects the UI that makes the dialog half-transparent but does not actually doable the input fields and\or buttons of the dialog:

here is a code sample:
[fiddle-code](http://jsfiddle.net/ArthurV/p7tV7/)

---

**EDIT:**

I have filed a ticket for jQuery-UI Dev. team and got a quick "duplicate" reply.
It seems that the `$("#myDialog").dialog("disable")` method for jQuery-UI Dialog will not disable the inputs but will change only the UI to look like it is disabled.
This feature is indeed not documented well enough.
here is a link to the tikect: [dialog('disable') does not disable OK/Cancel buttons inside dialog](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4606)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing, it looks like. There isn't much documentation on the `disable` method or what its actually supposed to do.

Apparently the `disable` method/option doesn't affect the *contents* of the dialog (or the buttons, which is a little weird), just the dialog itself. If you want to disable the inputs on the dialog I would disabling the buttons/inputs manually as well:

```
$("#UserDetailsDialog").dialog("disable")
    .closest(".ui-dialog")
    .find(":input")
    .prop("disabled", true);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/p7tV7/15/

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$( "#UserDetailsDialog" ).dialog( "option", "disabled", true );
```